# How to solve system of equations (boolean algebra)?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra

I have the following boolean algebra equations. They are supposed to be equivalent for $ab=FF, FT, TF$. I can show it with truth tables, but how can I prove it algebraically?
$$
\begin{cases}
x_1 = \neg (b \lor y_1) \\ \tag 1
y_1 = \neg (a \lor x_1)  \\
\end{cases}
$$
$$
\begin{cases}
x_2 = \neg (\neg a \land y_2) \\ \tag 2
y_2 =\neg (\neg b \land x_2) 
\end{cases}
$$
Starting with $x_1=x_2$:
\begin{align}
\neg (b \lor y_1)&=  \neg (\neg a \land y_2) \\
\neg b \land \neg y_1&=  a\lor\neg(y_2)\\ 
\end{align}
I'm stuck here.

For $y_1=y_2$ I have:
\begin{align}
\neg (a \lor x_1) &= \neg (\neg b \land x_2) \\
\neg a \land \neg x_1 &= b \lor \neg x_2 \\
\end{align}
I'm also stuck here, how to proceed?

Comment: What do you mean by them being "equivalent for ab = ....". What is equivalent to what and in what sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just plug in those different truth-value combination for $a$ and $b$.

So, for example, when $ab=FF$, you get:

$$
\begin{cases}
x_1 = \neg (F \lor y_1) = \neg y_1\\ \tag 1
y_1 = \neg (F \lor x_1) = \neg x_1 \\
\end{cases}
$$
$$
\begin{cases}
x_2 = \neg (\neg F \land y_2) = \neg (T \land y_2) = \neg y_2\\ \tag 2
y_2 =\neg (\neg F \land x_2) = \neg (T \land x_2) = \neg x_2\\
\end{cases}
$$

You can see these two sets of equations are equivalent, in that you can set $x_1=x_2$ and $y_1 = y_2$ to get the same equations.

Do the same for the other truth-value pairs ... and finally show that you do not get an equivalence when $ab=TT$.

I am not sure how to just take the equations and solve for $a$ and $b$ ... also because it is not clear that you always need to have that $x_1=x_2$ and $y_1=y_2$ in order to get equivalence: in the above example you can also set $x_1=y_2$ and $y_1=x_2$ to demonstrate equivalence.